# Fixing my gallery shortcode in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, thumbnails

I have been trying to figure out on how to fix my gallery shortcode in wordpress. Basically the objective is that user can place any size of images inside the shortcode and will not look stretch or distorted when viewed.

This is what is supposed to look like

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/Thumb_zpsf57e544b.jpg

This is what i have came up with when i coded it.

http://s255.photobucket.com/user/testament1234/media/thumbnail_zpsd95f993d.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0

If you notice the first image is missing a 5px margin at bottom. The 2nd and 3rd image is not touching the bottom of the div.

Here is the code for the function.ph

```
//Gallery Shortcode 2
function short_gallery($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(), $atts));
return '<div class=" gallery_box"><div class="inner_gallery"><a class="fancybox"  href="'.$content.'"><img src="'.$content.'"/></a></div></div>';
}
add_shortcode("gallery", "short_gallery");
```

And here is the code for my styling.

```
.gallery_box{background-color:#E8ECEF; float:left; margin:0px 20px 10px 0px; width:250px; height:200px; overflow:hidden }

.inner_gallery{margin:10px; margin:5px}
.inner_gallery img{max-width:100%; }
```

Been researching for hours on how i can achieve my desired results. It's ok if the image is crop as long it fits the container and the quality is not distored

Comment: Here is the link for the website http://chrisadebahr.com/my-beautiful-family/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your styles to match these:

-add border property to the gallery_box

```
.gallery_box{
background-color:#E8ECEF; 
float:left; 
margin:0px 20px 10px 0px; 
width:250px;     
height:200px; 
overflow:hidden; 
border:5px solid #E8ECEF; 
}
```

-remove the ".inner_gallery{margin:10px; margin:5px}" class

-change .inner_gallery img to:

```
.inner_gallery img{
  max-width : 400px;
  max-height : 400px;
}
```

It's a quick shortcut solution but it gets the job done. As long as you're ok with cropping.

Comment: Thanks i just tried out your solution it really works. I guess this would be a temporary solution. Not sure if there is a styling that can fit the whole image inside a fix container without losing the quality

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to set the image as the background image of its container (or the background image of the img tag, and set the src to a blank image for proper scaling):

```
<figure>
    <img src="BLANK_IMAGE_WITH_YOUR_TARGET_SIZE" style="background-image:url('URL')" alt="My Image" />
</figure>
```

Then set the background-size to cover:

```
figure { width:250px; border:solid 5px #666; margin:0 20px 10px 0; }
figure img { width:100%; background-size:cover; background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat; }
```

Comment: What is the difference with your codes sir. As of now I'm satisfied with the current solution :)

Comment: No problem, Jamie's solution is also correct. I'm just giving you a different approach to the problem.
My approach is pretty easy to scale up or down, which is good if you're going for a responsive design.
Let's say that your blank image's size is 250x200. You can easily scale it up to 500x400 or down to 100x80 by just adjusting the width of the figure.
The background-size:cover style is the important part here. It would scale and crop your image automatically depending on the size of its container. And you can also center the image without any effort.

Comment: hmmmm since you mention responsive i'll try it out later :)

Comment: Here's a sample implementation I did for a client, it's not fully responsive but you can see that the images scales up or down pretty well (and please don't mind the design, I only did the coding :D ) - http://turismopinoy.com/gallery/boracay